# Select a value of a view with view name and column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

What I have:

```
VIEW A 
uid name
10   test1
20   test2
30   test3
40   test4
```

What I want:

```
ViewName  ColName Row Value   
View A    uid     1   10
View A    name    1   test1
View A    uid     2   20
View A    name    2   test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign row numbers in a CTE and then unpivot with `UNION ALL`.

Notes:

- `uid` looks like an integer datatype while `name` is a string, so you need to convert `uid` to a `VARCHAR` else `UNION ALL` will raise an error.
- obviously the `ViewName` is harcoded in the query to `viewA`

Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'viewA' ViewName, uid, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY uid) rn FROM viewA
)
SELECT ViewName, 'uid' ColName, rn Row, CAST(uid AS varchar(50)) value FROM cte
UNION ALL SELECT ViewName, 'name' ColName, rn Row, name FROM cte
ORDER BY rn, ColName DESC
```

**[Demo on DB FIddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a99c605b8ddd03cf9b63a175ea892e4b)**:

```
ViewName | ColName | Row | value
:------- | :------ | :-- | :------
viewA    | uid     | 1   | 10              
viewA    | name    | 1   | test1           
viewA    | uid     | 2   | 20              
viewA    | name    | 2   | test2           
viewA    | uid     | 3   | 30              
viewA    | name    | 3   | test3           
viewA    | uid     | 4   | 40              
viewA    | name    | 4   | test4
```

Comment: Why not put ViewName in cte as well?

Comment: Any chance that the viewname could be generic? e.g. when I want to do that for more then 1 view at the same time

Comment: @Kovu: not really, since the view name is used in the query too... You would need to use dynamic SQL, which seems beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: dynamic SQL is onyl available in SPs rightß and a SP can't be called as View?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a union based on a subquery  on view_A

```
select  'View A', 'uid' colname, row_num,  uid value
from (
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY uid ASC) AS row_num, uid, name
from view_A

)
UNION ALL 
select  'View A', 'name', row_num,  name
from (SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY uid ASC) AS row_num, uid, name
from view_A)
ORDER BY row_num, colname
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
DECLARE @ViewName NVARCHAR(64) = 'ViewA'
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @Query = ' 
SELECT  ' + '''' + @ViewName + + '''' + ' AS ViewName,
        C.[name] AS ColName,
        V.[name] AS [Value],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY V.[Uid] ) AS [Row]
FROM    ' + @ViewName + ' AS V
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = OBJECT_ID(' + '''' + @ViewName + '''' + ')'
        print @Query

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

Comment: The apostroph is not escaped :)

Comment: Not working, way to much rows. I think your inner join has the wrong on clause